# How to read os.system call stdout stderr?

Tags: python, operating-system, system, interpreter, qgis

So it so happens that our interpriter (QGis) overrides `subprocess.run` and its components. And I want to use alternative python, libraries stack.  So the only way I can start all I need is with `os.system` call. On that call I start an executable script (.bat file). I want to get what was outputted by it. Are there ways to hoock into  `os.system` call to get it or file/server syncronisation is the easiest rout?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly `subprocess.run` is what you need, where `os.system` is simply a throw and forget solution.

Option 1, if this work, have you tried to reimport `subprocess` with an other name? Depending on how the override is done, this may work.

```
import subprocess as sub2
```

Option 2, you’re right, in pure os.system, by writing to files, you can reimplement a process monitoring and check outputs. But this will have high development and compute costs.

Option 3, if only run is overridden, maybe can you give a chance to `subprocess.Popen()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `subprocess` but you can use `os`, then try `os.popen()`

This works on my Windows 10 VM

```py
>>> import os
>>> directory = os.popen("dir").read()
>>> print(directory)
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1C6C-2DB6

 Directory of C:\Users\Test User

04/21/2022  04:46 AM    <DIR>          .
04/21/2022  04:46 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/23/2021  01:49 AM    <DIR>          .android
04/21/2022  04:46 AM    <DIR>          .idlerc
05/07/2021  01:04 AM    <DIR>          .ssh
07/17/2020  08:02 AM    <DIR>          .VirtualBox
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          3D Objects
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
12/03/2021  11:04 PM    <DIR>          Desktop
11/05/2021  06:58 PM    <DIR>          Documents
12/03/2021  11:43 PM    <DIR>          Downloads
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Favorites
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Links
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Music
08/16/2021  09:28 PM    <DIR>          OneDrive
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Pictures
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Saved Games
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Searches
11/05/2021  06:08 PM    <DIR>          Videos
11/05/2021  05:01 PM    <DIR>          VirtualBox VMs
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              20 Dir(s)  33,398,673,408 bytes free
```